# Welcome to the potion shop. What do we have for sale, again..?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, potions

Preparing a game and I've got a few NPCs with some undefined loot: "first level potion," It got me to wondering - **is there a consolidated list of potions, maybe oils too, for DnD 3.5?** I found the start of a Pathfinder one but it was still bare bones. Does this already exist, or **is it necessary to forge one's own with available books?**

While I'm aware of [the SRD list](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/potionsAndOils.htm), I wonder if there's a more comprehensive list of potions available for purchase? Even just the book and price or spell level would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, a list of spells would be enough, right?

Crystalkeep indexes are good. Well, they were before Spell Compendium was released. They got removed from crystalkeep, IIRC, but I still have them and can upload them to Dropbox or somewhere, if needed. **Speaking of Crystalkeep, they used to have magic item index as well, potions included**.

[WotC index](https://web.archive.org/web/20191221174239/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/lists/spells) is a list of PHB + Spell Compendium spells, spell levels, spell areas/targets/effects and pages included.

There may be more.

Comment: Wow, I was not aware of the WotC index -- that'll be incredibly useful for looking up spells in the compendium!  It's unfortunate that it doesn't have any filtering functionality, since filtering by range/targets would let you get the list of valid potions.

Comment: +1 a list of spells is rather nice, I'd forgotten about the WotC index. That list is bulky, but with some spreadsheet tweaking I'm sure it'll become more usable. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 2):

These 2 links are random generators.  These generators have been a great help to me in making my own towns, shops, treasure etc.  If I had to name a drawback its that by being non system specific they do not have a lot of material from the splats.  However, if you have an item you want you can always swap it out with an item of equal value from the randomized list (or just add it on top).  Don't let that sway you away though, these are still MUST HAVE links.

This one has a [Magic Shop & More](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/magic/shop.html).  This one can separate by size of town and the type of shop you are at. (ie, alchemist shop, weapon shop etc.  In addition to magic shop, this 2nd link can also be used to randomize treasure or even towns & NPCs (Names/race/levels etc, but it does not stat out their character sheet for you).  If you are making your own town this link is a MUST!

This one is strictly a [Magic Item Shop](http://www.inkwellideas.com/roleplaying_tools/magic_item_shop/) generator.  It can be used to breakdown how much is available by size of the "town" or even customize your own shop without caring about the suggested town size limits.  While not as many generators as the first link, it lets you break down by what type of magic item you want (wands/scrolls/major/minor etc..) & you can select LOTs of Magic Items

Hope this helps!

Comment: I love Donjon's stuff, and the other one I've come to now and then. It's not much help for finding *specifically* something to fit a 50gp potion/oil slot though, but my question didn't specify that terribly strongly.